# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am following the tutorials from the link : https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config without any customization yet facing the below error while starting the server.

Could anyone please help me with the error ?

The error below for reference.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'endpointHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcEndpoints' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentMvcEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'environmentMvcEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c55afa25]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration$GitRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.baeldung.spring.cloud.config.server.ConfigServer.main(ConfigServer.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'endpointHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcEndpoints' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentMvcEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'environmentMvcEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c55afa25]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration$GitRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRemoteException: Invalid remote: origin
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Looks like there is a mismatch between different spring boot dependencies in your project.

Comment: @Anand - Please take a look at the Project and update to new version and see if you're also getting same error ?